# Using the ssSetTNext S-function macro outside of mdlGetTimeOfNextVarHit method

Tags: matlab, simulink, s-function

[The Simulink documentation for `ssSetTNext`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/simulink/sfg/sssettnext.html) says that:
"A discrete S-function with a variable sample time should use this macro in `mdlGetTimeOfNextVarHit` to specify the time of the next sample hit".

Now, I'd like to compute the next sample hit for the S-function **after** the execution of `mdlOutputs`. However, according to [Simulink Engine Interaction with C S-Functions](http://www.mathworks.com/help/simulink/sfg/how-the-simulink-engine-interacts-with-c-s-functions.html?searchHighlight=simulink+engine), `mdlGetTimeOfNextVarHit` is executed **before** `mdlOutputs` (see the picture describing the Simulation Loop).

On the other hand, the documentation for `mdlUpdate` (unfortunately, I'm not allowed to post the link) says that:
"The method can also perform any other tasks that the S-function needs to perform at each major time step".

Since `mdlUpdate` is executed **after** `mdlOutputs`, I was wondering if it's safe to ignore the method `mdlGetTimeOfNextVarHit` and put all the logics defining the next sample hit (and also use `ssSetTNext`) inside `mdlUpdate`.

Thank you in advance.

--Matteo

Answer (score 0):

**In short, yes.**

It is possible to set the variable-rate task's next hit time outside of the `mdlGetTimeOfNextVarHit()` method. The next sample instant simply must be set before the end of the present simulation loop: it may therefore be set either in the `mdlOutputs()` or `mdlUpdate()` methods.

Remember that C-MEX S-Functions configured to use a variable timestep task still require:

- that `MDL_GET_TIME_OF_NEXT_VAR_HIT` be defined, and
- an implementation/definition of `mdlGetTimeOfNextVarHit()`.

This means that if you wish to set your new sample instant elsewhere, you still need a (potentially empty) definition for `mdlGetTimeOfNextVarHit()`.

**Gotcha's:**

If `MDL_GET_TIME_OF_NEXT_VAR_HIT` is not defined for a C-MEX S-Function configured to use a variable timestep task and there is no definition for `mdlGetTimeOfNextVarHit()`; compilation will succeed, but upon invocation the following error diagnostic will be reported, and the simulation will terminate:

> To have a variable sample time, define MDL_GET_TIME_OF_NEXT_VAR_HIT and add a mdlGetTimeOfNextVarHit routine.

Lastly, if `MDL_GET_TIME_OF_NEXT_VAR_HIT` is not defined but there is a definition of `mdlGetTimeOfNextVarHit()`, compilation will fail.